# How to perform SQL query using .STContains in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry

I have a table that stores polygons and a table that stores points with a value field. Both sets of data are stored using the Geometry type in MS SQL Server.

I have a simple requirement - I need to retrieve the records of points that are contained within the polygons and then sum the result based on a value field in the points table. So, the end result of the query is two columns:
- polygon names
- sum of the value field in the point table

```
DECLARE @area GEOMETRY  = (SELECT Shape FROM GREENFIELDAREAS WHERE AREANAME = 'Aerodrome')
SELECT NETDWELLINGS, Shape FROM ORA_NETDWELLINGCOMPLETIONS WHERE @area.STIntersects(Shape) = 1
```

The above query returns point geometries but only for 1 polygon (Aerodrome). What I need is to sum NETDWELLINGS and return that value for all the polygons.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT g.id , SUM(o.netdwellings) as sum from g , o  WHERE g.geom.STIntersects(o.geom) = 1 group by g.id
```

That would return sum of all o.geoms that intersect with g.geom. 
(did i understood question wrong ?)

Comment: Thanks heaps, that's exactly what I need. You understood the question perfectly :) I can't see a tick mark next to your response - how do I mark it as answered? Thanks again for your quick response.

Comment: Hi @EdSaunders! Welcome to GIS SE!  You'll need just a little more reputation before you'll see the green Accept button so for now just upvote useful answers.  In the meantime I'll convert your "answer" here to a comment.